# Partition std::vector of 2D points

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

Suppose I have a `std::vector<Point>` where `Point` is `struct Point { double x; double y;}`
I'd like to partition such a vector into groups (buckets), where all Points in same bucket have same Euclidean norm between each other (e.g dist(PointA,PointB) == X, where X is constant). I've decided to use `std::map` for such task with custom sorting operator:

```
struct ClosePoints
{
    bool operator()(Point const& A, Point const& B) const
    {
        bool same = dist(A,B) < x;
        //If not close enough use lexical sort
        return same ? false : std::tie(A.x, A.y) < std::tie(B.x,); 
    }
}
```

Partitioning code:

```
std::map<Point, std::list<Point>, ClosePoints> map;
for(const auto& p : pointsVector)
    map[p].push_back(p);
```

After some testing and printing the buckets I've noticed that some points that do obey given Euclidean norm limit `X` ended in different buckets.
I can't figure out why is it so ?

Comment: I suggest that you provide a complete, compilable and working example, including test input, that can reproduce your problem.

Comment: 1) What is `x`?  2) What is `dist()`?  3) What if `dist(A,B) < x` returned the same value as `dist(B, A) < x`?  If so, then you have a `strict-weak-ordering` issue.

Comment: You operator doesn't follow strict ordering, as `A <= A + eps` and `A + eps <= A + 2 * eps`, but not `A <= A + 2 * eps`.

Comment: If you posted a [mcve] along with the data that causes the issue, then the program can be run on Visual Studio with the debug switch on.  VS detects issues with strict-weak-ordering at runtime and will assert() if the s.w.o criteria doesn't hold.

Comment: std::map is tree based container. When inserting into tree container you must decide whether going to left descendants or right descendants of each tree node. So my Idea was to use map's operator[] when A < B && B > A --> same point, otherwise sort first by X break tie By Y (lexical sort)

Comment: @JobNick -- ok, so what would happen if say the runtime gives you (A, B) and you return a value.  Then the runtime calls your function, but this time (B, A) **and you return the same value** as (A, B).  If that happens, then your sort is screwed up, i.e you're violating the strict-weak-ordering.  This technique of switching the parameters and calling the function twice is the trick that Visual Studio uses to detect these violations.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie but how does operator[] finds a value ? If I search for a value X in a tree then X is found if exists such  Y tree node that X < Y && Y < X yields true

Comment: @JobNick -- How many points are there?  For kicks, call `std::sort(yourPoints.begin(), yourPoints.end(), ClosePoints);` and check the results.  If you see that the points are not sorted, then that's why `std::map` is also having issues.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie there about ~200 points and yes, they are not sorted

Comment: Then I think you should work on why std::sort didn't sort the points.  And saying that, you're lucky that `std::sort` didn't just go in an infinite loop or crash.  Can you go to [this site](http://ideone.com/) and copy / paste the data into the `stdin` window and hit "Run".  Then give back the link so that the data can be accessible to others to test it?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie sorting algorithm have no problem coping with equal elements. Therefor sorting algorithm can be stable or not stable (which std::sort is)

Comment: @JobNick -- It is not that the elements are equal.  What is at issue is that you're returning the same `true / false` value in your predicate for two given elements.  Again, this is how VS checks these things -- your predicate is called twice, first with (A,B), and then with (B,A), and if the results are the same for each invocation, the runtime will abort due to a violation in the s.w.o.  In other words, you're telling the sort criteria that A comes before B, and at the same time B comes before A.  Unfortunately you must be using a compiler that doesn't have this check as a debugging aide.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie actually I'm compiling with MSVC2013 and I did notice that my predicate called twice while I was debugging. I sought it was called twice to determine if it is the same element (as I was using operator[] which 1. return reference to mapped value if key exists 2. Adds Key to map and return reference to default constructed mapped type. No assert was invoked during debugging

Comment: The predicate is called twice for `std::sort` to determine if there is a strict weak order violation.  Using the `std::sort` test is much more thorough than inserting data in a `std::map` manually, since you don't know in advance what two items are going to be tested for "less than".  Second, there is a `std::is_sorrted` function that checks if the sequence is indeed sorted which you could use.  Otherwise, all I can say is that the data *is* sorted, but not sorted based on how you want it to be sorted -- that would have you debug your predicate to make sure it is working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that comparison operator that you defined does not provide equivalence relationship. For instance, you can have a point B that close to A and C but points A and C could be far from each other. Thus, if you compare B with A and C, you will put them in the same basket as B. However, if you compere A and C first, results will be unpredictable.

Comment: This is correct in general case, but in my case (data I'm working on) such points A B C from your example will all obey the distance: (A,B) (B,C) (C,A) will all have the same distance between each other

Comment: @JobNick OK, I assume you have subsets with distance from each other larger than x, and each subset could be placed in the ball with radius x. Then your logic is correct. However, you need to order different subsets to make operator work. This does not have a solution since operator could be based only on geometrical characteristic of the whole subset, for instance, average coordinate of all elements, min or max of some coordinate for the whole subset. It could be easily proved.

Comment: I think that the problem is the order of elements insertion. Maybe at some point in time when the tree re-balance itself insertion of elements which already has a representative set creates it's own tree node (set).